# How can I create an analog signal which is similar to PMT (Photo Multiplier Tube) pulse using analog write?

Tags: analogwrite

I have developed a circuit to process the PMT pulse output. For the testing, I need an artificial signal which is similar to the PMT pulse. How can I use `AnalogWrite()` to create such type of signal?

[image: Attached image show the waveform of PMT Pulse]

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for a way to generate a pulse as in the picture? The pulse is 40 ns. The Arduino AVR family of boards will have a hard time doing that!

Comment: Or do you mean a cascade of pulses with random width, duration and delay? All in the range of micro-seconds.

Comment: The PWM frequency of Arduinoboards is normally 490Hz, that means the shortest puls using `analogWrite(PIN, 1)` would last 8000ns.

Comment: You could write 200 NOPs @ 62.5ns each, assuming a 16MHz clock (minus overheads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

The Arduino can't do analog output at all, much less matching a specific analog waveform of ≈40ns duration.

PWM on the Arduino simulates **constant** analog voltages using square wave pulses of variable duty cycle. It has no support for creating analog waveforms of any type, much less ones with such a short duration.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in this thread: [Generate a ramp input with an Arduino Uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/62816/generate-a-ramp-input-with-an-arduino-uno)

You could use a resistor ladder to create a roll-your-own DAC, and then use direct port register manipulation (not digitalWrite) to set the pins controlling your resistor ladder and get a crude approximation of your waveform.

**Edit #2**

There is no way you'll be able to generate nanosecond scale waveforms with a normal Arduino. It just isn't fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much AVR-based Arduinos could do that.

SAMD21-based Arduinos do have a DAC, but their conversion time is about 2.85 μs. Their timer/counters can be clocked at 96 MHz, so about 10.5 ns/tick, but would yield a square pulse (that may or may not degenerate into what you need 8-).

Overall, I don't think an Arduino is the right tool for the job. Maybe something like the (very fast) Teensy 4.0 could do it, but I don't know much about those.